# Obtain Timeout from existing TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I have an existing `TransactionScope` and want to obtain the `TransactionOptions.Timeout` used to create the scope. How?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.